# whats wrong with this query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have this in my table model called Table

$test = $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('table.test_id is NULL'),
        'order'=>       array('table.created ASC'),
                        )
                    );

it doesnt work. Tryingt to get the latest row with some criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, to get the latest row, you would want to organize by the `created` field descending, rather than ascending. Also, there are some problems with your syntax, that I have cleaned up below.

```
$this->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('Table.test_id'=>NULL), 'order'=>array('Table.created'=>'desc')));
```